# HTML5 time input displays 1 hour less than the actual time

Tags: html, time, input

I am trying to input the current time as returned by new Date()...

```
$('#TSE').val(new Date().toJSON().substring(11,16));
```

...in a time input field:

```
<input type="time" id="TSE">
```

The value has the format hh:mm and is accepted by the input field.

The problem is that it is displaying **1 hour less** than the actual time.

For example, if new Date() would be **2012-11-16T11:59**, the input field would show **10:59**

I am experiencing this problem with Safari Mobile (web app). My timezone is CET (GMT+1). We lost DST a few weeks ago.

Thank you.

Comment: CET = UTC+1 btw, strictly speaking :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#TSE').val(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're displaying the time incorrectly. Here's what happens:

```
> new Date().toJSON()
'2012-11-16T12:08:42.914Z'
> new Date().toJSON().substring(11,16)
'12:08'
```

`'toJSON()` converts the date into UTC and formats w/r/t [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The date has a 'Z' at the end; this indicates UTC.

It makes sense for `.toJSON()` to perform this conversion, as it's good for dates to be normalized for storage or transfer. For display in UI, it's better to use another formatting function though.

See also: [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks. I am using toJSON() because I "saw it somewhere". I tried toString() and can extract time and date the same way.